# ArangoDB create edge collection

Tags: c#, graph, nosql, arangodb

I tried create collection of edges in c# via ArangoDB-NET driver (https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET) and this code not working.. My code:

```
 var response = dbClient.Collection.Type(ACollectionType.Edge).KeyGeneratorType(AKeyGeneratorType.Autoincrement).WaitForSync(true).Create(
                "EdgesCollection");
```

dbClient is ADatabase object.
Collection is created but document type is not edge. How can I do?

Comment: anyone help me? :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that driver, and your question seems to be related to implementation, not DB functionality.  However, my best guess would be to omit the `KeyGeneratorType` and `WaitForSync` options:

```cs
var cType = ACollectionType.Edge;
var cName = "EdgesCollection";
var response = dbClient.Collection.Type(cType).Create(cName);
```

If this fails to work, then you may need to review the [docs](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/blob/master/docs/CollectionOperations.md#create-collection), maybe add some other options like `KeyIncrement`.  Generally, I would accept the defaults and only modify (or provide explicit parameters for) things that you ***NEED*** to change (i.e. "don't work").